# How to sign an apk through command line

Tags: android, apk, signed-apk

Be informed that we have created an apk file through command line with the help of Android SDK. Now since uploading it to google play store needs the apk to be signed. How shall we do this.

Answer (score 27):

1. First you need a keystore to begin the process. You will be signing your apk with this keystore and you need to sign with same keystore for future updates. Know more about keystore here: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key
2. Once you generate the keystore, you should `jarsigner` utility (which is available in JDK folder)

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore your-release-key.keystore android-release-unsigned.apk alias -storepass password
```

3. Next step is to use `zipalign` tool(available in android SDK folder) to verify the apk.

```
path-to-android-sdk/build-tools/version/zipalign -v 4 android-release-unsigned.apk android-prod-released-signed.apk
```

4. Last step is to verify with `apksigner` tool (available in android SDK folder)

```
path-to-android-sdk/build-tools/version/apksigner verify android-prod-released-signed.apk
```

PS: Replace paths, files and passwords with actual values

Comment: What is the purpose of step number 2?

Answer (score 23):

### Step 1

First you need to generate a private signing key

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

This command will prompt you for a password for your keystore and key (also for some additional fields). Please remember to keep your **keystore** file **private** at anytime.

### Step 2

Next you need to setup gradle

1. Place `my-release-key.keystore` which you generated in Step 1 under `android/app`
2. Update your `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` under `android/app` and add the following

   ```
   MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.keystore
   MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
   MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=<The password you choose earlier with the keytool>
   MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=<The password you choose earlier with the keytool>
   ```

### Step 3

Finally you need to update your `android/app/build.gradle`.

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig { ... }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can simply generate a signed release via the command line by running the following command in your android directory

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

The generated apk can then be found under your `build/outputs/apk/release` directory.

Comment: The other two steps can be done for sure. But the first step, when i run that command in cli, it is saying it is not recognized internal command. What shall i do.

Comment: I assume you are on windows, if this is the case you need to run the key tool from ```C:\Program Files\Java\jdkx.x.x_x\bin```

Comment: not all android apk's are create in Android Studio, so this only applies to 60% of dev teams. The other answers are better. I doubt this could even be achieved on a pipeline without hosting it yourself

Answer (score 22):

Follow these commands to make the apk play store ready:

**Step 1: Create an unsigned apk:**

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

**Step 2: Create a signed apk:**

```
jarsigner -keystore YOUR_KEYSTORE_PATH -storepass YOUR_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk YOUR_KEY_ALIAS
```

**Step 3: Zipaligning the apk:**

```
your_android-sdk_path/android-sdk/build-tools/your_build_tools_version/zipalign -v 4 app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk release.apk
```

Comment: Please note: [If you use apksigner, zipalign must only be performed **before** the APK file has been signed.](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/zipalign)

Answer (score 4):

In case it help in future.

From android developer [doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#sign_manually), remember that:

> If you want to sign an app bundle from the command line, you can use jarsigner. If instead you want to sign an APK, you need to use zipalign and apksigner as described below.

So for an apk:

- *apk* not signed in 'C:\Users\User\Downloads\unsigned.apk'
- *zipalign.exe* in 'C:\android\android-sdk\build-tools\$version$\zipalign.exe'
- *apksigner.bat* in 'C:\android\android-sdk\build-tools\$version$\apksigner.bat'
- *keystore* in 'C:\Keystores\my.keystore'

1. To align: $.\zipalign.exe -v -p 4 'C:\Users\User\Downloads\unsigned.apk' 'C:\Users\User\Downloads\aligned.apk'

   - To verify: $.\zipalign.exe -v -c 4 'C:\Users\User\Downloads\aligned.apk'
2. To sign: $.\apksigner.bat sign --ks 'C:\Keystores\my.keystore' --out 'C:\Users\User\Downloads\signed.apk' 'C:\Users\User\Downloads\aligned.apk'

   - Insert keystore password
   - To verify: $.\apksigner.bat verify 'C:\Users\User\Downloads\signed.apk'

For an aab:

- *aab* not signed in 'C:\Users\User\Downloads\unsigned.aab'
- *jarsigner.exe* in 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2\bin\jarsigner.exe'
- *keystore* in 'C:\Keystores\my.keystore'

1. To sign: $jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA-256 -keystore 'C:\Keystores\my.keystore' -signedjar 'C:\Users\User\Downloads\signed.aab' 'C:\Users\User\Downloads\unsigned.aab' '<my keystore alias>'

   - Insert keystore password